# QLPreviewController - setting previewItemTitle

Tags: iphone, qlpreviewcontroller

I can't work out how to set the previewItemTitle property for my QLPreviewController class. Its seems a bit strange as the iPhone developer document for this class says that that property is `@property (readonly)` which would mean that I cannot set it.

Any ideas. Thanks

My code:

```
QLPreviewController *preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    [preview setDataSource:self];

    [self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

QLPreviewController has no previewItemTitle property. You mean the QLPreviewItem *protocol*.

"Readonly" means that you can't set it *via the property* (unless it's overridden); i.e. the property does not declare a `setPreviewItemTitle:` method. This makes sense for the protocol: the controller does not expect to be able to set the preview item titles.

For the most basic preview item, you could use something like this:

```
@interface BasicPreviewItem : NSObject<QLPreviewItem>
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL * previewItemURL;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* previewItemTitle;

@end

@implementation BasicPreviewItem

@synthesize previewItemURL, previewItemTitle;

-(void)dealloc
{
  self.previewItemURL = nil;
  self.previewItemTitle = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

However, the point of the protocol is so that you can take *any* class and add `-(NSURL*)previewItemURL` and `-(NSString*)previewItemTitle` methods (e.g. if you had a music player, you could add those methods to the "Track" class and be able to preview tracks).

Comment: Is there anyway to remove or hide the "Share" button on the navigation/tool bar?